# React Form controlled component inputs

Tags: reactjs, react-forms, controlled-component

I have the following component hierarchy:

```
     App
      |
   |------|
Results  Form
```

So the Results and Form components are children of the App component. I am trying to implement controlled inputs in the Form. I have my `state` in the `App` component as I want to display the data from the form inputs in the `Results` component. I am getting the `Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input to be controlled` error when I don't set initial values for the state and try to use the form. When I set initial values in the state, these values are displayed in the inputs which is not what I want when a user first goes to the form. What is the best solution to this problem of having to set the state to avoid the React Warning but not wanting to display values in the input prior to the user even using the form?

Comment: You can set the default state to an empty value. `useState("")`

Answer (score 0):

If you get such an error most likely because you don't have a state that handles the form input:

Here's an example:

App.js

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import Form from "./Form";
import Result from "./Result";

export default function App() {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  return (
    <>
      <Form input={input} inputHandler={setInput} />
      <Result result={input} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Form.js

```js
export default function Form({ input, inputHandler }) {
  return (
    <form>
      <input value={input} onChange={(e) => inputHandler(e.target.value)} />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Result.js

```js
export default function Result({ result }) {
  return <span>Your input is: {result}</span>;
}
```